# Merging multiple JSON objects from an array together

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, mapreduce, lodash

I have an array of JSON objects and I want to merge the objects that have the same text together while finding the average of relevance and the sum of count across all of the same instances.

```js
var keywords = [
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.626303,
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.87319,
                "count": 5
            },
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.05,
                "count": 100
            },
            {
                "text": "restaurants",
                "relevance": 0.614567,
                "count": 16
            },
            {
                "text": "restaurants",
                "relevance": 0.609875,
                "count": 4
            },
            {
                "text": "hotels",
                "relevance": 0.594905,
                "count": 1
            },
```

I tried [the solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29915857/1422062) but, I am getting an output like this:

```
{
    text: 'service businesses',
    count: '[object Object][object Object]'
  }
```

The output I am hoping for would look like this:

```
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.516497667,
                "count": 106
            },

            {
                "text": "restaurants",
                "relevance": 0.612221,
                "count": 20
            },
            {
                "text": "hotels",
                "relevance": 0.594905,
                "count": 1
            },
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to post your code so we can see how you incorrectly applied the solution and show how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can group the elements by the text and based on that group data, can get the output as follows.

```js
var keywords = [{
    "text": "service businesses",
    "relevance": 0.626303,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "text": "service businesses",
    "relevance": 0.87319,
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "text": "service businesses",
    "relevance": 0.05,
    "count": 100
  },
  {
    "text": "restaurants",
    "relevance": 0.614567,
    "count": 16
  },
  {
    "text": "restaurants",
    "relevance": 0.609875,
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "text": "hotels",
    "relevance": 0.594905,
    "count": 1
  }
];

const groupBy = keywords.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.text] ? acc[cur.text] = {
    ...acc[cur.text],
    count: acc[cur.text].count + cur.count,
    relevance: [...acc[cur.text].relevance, cur.relevance]
  } : acc[cur.text] = {
    ...cur,
    relevance: [cur.relevance]
  };
  return acc;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(groupBy).map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  relevance: item.relevance.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / item.relevance.length
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much @derek.w :)

Answer (score -1):

I ran it in two for loops and then calculated the relevance on the second loop.

I just kept track of the values in a normal object.

```js
var keywords = [
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.626303,
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.87319,
                "count": 5
            },
            {
                "text": "service businesses",
                "relevance": 0.05,
                "count": 100
            },
            {
                "text": "restaurants",
                "relevance": 0.614567,
                "count": 16
            },
            {
                "text": "restaurants",
                "relevance": 0.609875,
                "count": 4
            },
            {
                "text": "hotels",
                "relevance": 0.594905,
                "count": 1
            }
          ]

const objectMerge = (arr) => {
  let map = {};
  for(let idx in arr){
    const { text, relevance, count } = arr[idx];
    if(!map[text]){
      map[text] = {
        count: 0,
        relevance: []
      }
    }
    map[text].count += count
    map[text].relevance.push(relevance)
  }
  for(const key in map){
    let lenOfRelevance = map[key].relevance.length
    map[key].relevance = map[key].relevance.reduce((a,b) => a+b) / lenOfRelevance
  }
  return map
}

console.log(objectMerge(keywords))
```